C# Using Resource files on Linux in 2024
two days now chasing my tail on this (blame Google and Bing)
I have a new, small, C# .NET 8.0 console based, project that I was trying to add 'localization' of messages to.
This MUST be platform agnostic - at least handle Linux and Windows.
Because of this requirement I have been using Visual Studio Code (1.90) and, up until this step, the code has been happily swapping between the two operating systems.
Basically how can I use resource files (or some other simple 'localization' alternative ) in a .Net project for Linux

NOT how do I create resource files.
NOT how to use ResGen because that seems not to exist on Linux
must NOT rely on the full 'Visual Studio' just 'Visual Studio Code'
must be current advice - ie ideas that work in .NET 8

I just cant seem to be able to fashion a question to the search engines that does not result in articles 10 or more years old and refering to things like .Net 1.1 and so on.
I am new to this .NET stuff but was hoping I could find current examples - without knowing the whole history of every step of .NET to know when something went out of style.
And as you guess can guess its vitrually impossible to get results for 'Visual Studio Code' without a million things telling how to do it it 'Visual Studio' - why could they not pick a really different name for different products? (They had no problem inventing other meaningless names like 'Entra', 'Yamma', 'Viva')
Well now that I have that rant off my chest -- do you have any suggestions how I might achieve this?
Thanks
JC

Do you need to be able to build on both platforms or just run the binaries on both?

Build on both I would say.

So I gave up with the possibility of using .Net for this and wrote my own.
It will allow code to use different language Resource file but left in text format.
It happily works across platform (Windows and Linux).
see https://github.com/jc508/poorMansLocalization
Just offered for anybody else in the dual platform delima
JC
